# how do i create a table from a dict using django-tables2

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I have a list of dict that look like this:

```
 [set([u'meal', '0:08:35.882945']),
  set([0, u'personal']),
  set([0, u'sleep']),
  set([0, u'transport']),
  set([0, u'work'])]
```

That I made from :

```
[u'meal',u'personal', u'sleep', u'transport', u'work']
['0:08:35.882945', 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

With this command:

```
nob =  [{m,n} for m,n in zip(cats,tot3)]
```

How can I turn this into a [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) table?

I tried this :

```
# tables.py
class Small_table (tables.Table):
    category = tables.Column(verbose_name="category")
    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}

# views.py
nt = Small_table(nob)
RequestConfig(request).configure(nt)
```

But the table has one column of dashes rather than my data, what should I change?

Comment: Note: Be aware that `nob` is not a list of dictionaries but a list of sets.

Comment: What should be in category column? You should have one row from this data or five?

Comment: @PeterStahl my bad, i dont know how to change it to a list of dicts.

Comment: @sneawo i want five rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what i ended up doing:

in my tables.py:

```
class Small_table (tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(verbose_name="category",order_by="name")
    tot  = tables.Column(orderable=False)
    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

in my view

```
from .tables import Small_table
from django_tables2   import RequestConfig
nob =  [{"name":m,"tot":n} for m,n in zip(cats,tot3)]
nt = Small_table(nob)
RequestConfig(request).configure(nt)
return render(request, "job/job_home.html", { "small":nt })
```

and in the template:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue
{% render_table small %}
```

Comment: Why are you using such a complicated approach for the simple task of displaying data in a table?

Comment: @PeterStahl im creating a timer app thats going to have lots of tables with totals calculated on the time spent and so on, i think i will have about 4 unique pages (some pages are date based so when a user navigates to the date they get a table with stuff relevant to that date) with at least 4 or so tables in each, id rather just create an array of tables and have django-tables2 do the heavy lifting on the templates and table generation logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this django-tables app, but if your goal is to simply display your data in a table, I would do it like that:

1. Your data structure is much too complicated. Simply create a list of tuples and return it as your template context.

   ```
   >>> a = [u'meal', u'personal', u'sleep', u'transport', u'work']
   >>> b =  ['0:08:35.882945', 0, 0, 0, 0]
   >>> nob = zip(a, b)
   >>> nob 
   [(u'meal', '0:08:35.882945'),
    (u'personal', 0),
    (u'sleep', 0),
    (u'transport', 0),
    (u'work', 0)]
   ```
2. In your template, you can then do:

   ```
   <table> 
   {% for i, j in nob %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ i }}</td>
           <td>{{ j }}</td>
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   </table>
   ```

This creates a row with two cells in the table for each entry in `nob`. Now you may see why a list of sets is not a good idea here. Sets don't preserve the ordering of elements, i.e. `{{ i }}` would sometime be taken from list `a` and sometimes from list `b` whereas you want `{{ i }}` always to be taken from list `a` and `{{ j }}` always to be taken from list `b`.