# Django_tables2: Create table from dictionary

Tags: django, datatables, django-tables2

I am using [django_tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to change my tables to [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). However I am really confused as to how do I go ahead with this. Im my view `campaigns.py` I have this(this file has other 1 other class with 2 methods):

```
class CampaignListView(FacebookAdInit):
    """ CampaignListView for viewing all the campaigns"""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ad_account = self.get_ad_account(kwargs.get('ad_account_id'))

        campaigns = self.get_campaigns(ad_account.get('id')) \
            if ad_account else None
        context = {'campaigns': campaigns, 'ad_account': ad_account}

        return render(request, 'app/campaigns/index.html', context)
```

I display the `context` dictionary as a table in my template: `campaigns/index.html`by using the `<table>,<td> and <tr>` HTML tags:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="campaigns">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> #</th>
        <th> Campaign Name</th>
        <th> Campaign Objective</th>
        <th> Campaign Effective Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for campaign in campaigns %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ forloop.counter }} </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/ad_accounts/{{ ad_account.id }}/campaigns/{{ campaign.id }}/ad_sets">
                    {{ campaign.name }} </a>
            </td>
            <td> {{ campaign.objective }}</td>
            <td> {{ campaign.effective_status }} </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now how on earth do I go ahead making this a 'paginated' datatable. Ive gone through countless SO questions and [this one looked helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850268/how-do-i-create-a-table-from-a-dict-using-django-tables2), but how do I import my view into the `tables.py` and where do I place the `tables.py` file if my structure is :

```
folder\
 migrations\
 static\
 templates\
  app\
   #a whole bunch of templates
 views\
  campaigns.py
 __init__.py
 models.py
 forms.py
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to use django-tables2 in the code you posted: you are running your own table template, which is fine, but not the intended way of using django-tables2.

Django-table2 is also not meant to provide the data to a datatables-instance. It might work, but it intended to generate static html tables.